# How can I refer to url params in my rails javascript template using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

My javascript is:

```
$(function(){
  $("a[data-toggle-length]='toggle'").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("span.show_hide").toggleClass("shown hidden");
    $("table").toggleClass("wide narrow");
    // here  
    $.get('/toggle_full_details');
  }); 
});
```

I want to add to this js, something like (just before the `$.get` call above):

```
if (params[:focus_on_first_field]) == "1" { 
  $("input[type='text']:first").focus();
}
```

But `params[:focus_on_first_field]` is the rails way to refer to a url parameter and gives me a syntax error here.

How can I refer to the url param in javascript?  I can use jquery if it makes it easier. I already use it elsewhere.

The haml view is;

```
= render partial: 'links', :locals => {:first_field_focus => 1 }
```

which calls a partial which uses:

```
- this_first_field_focus = ((first_field_focus ||= 0) == 1) ? 1 : 0
...
= render partial: 'toggle_details_link_bold', :locals => {:txt => "Summary / 
<b>Details</b>",     :show_hide => 'shown', :first_field_focus => this_first_field_focus}
```

and then uses another partial, which has the hyperlink:

```
%a{href: '#', :data => {toggle_length: 'toggle', first_field_focus: first_field_focus}}
```

I tried using

```
...
// here
if ($(location).attr('data-first-field-focus') == "1") {
  $("input[type='text']:first").focus();
} 
...
```

but it didn't work (but no console errors either)

Without the `attr` condition, `$("input[type='text']:first").focus();` does work on its own.

Comment: Yeah, you can do AJAX calls. Create a helper method that returns params[:focus_on_first_field] and use ajax to call this method.

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter